# Push new data from Node REST API to React-Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, react-native, push-notification

***Problem***

I've created a REST API using Node and a client app using React-Native.

So far I've configured it so the client app makes HTTP requests to the server.

Now I need to push new data from the server to the client as soon as it is available.  I need to push different data to the client app depending on which user is logged in.

I haven't done this before and I've been having trouble finding a good solution online, partially because I don't know the correct terminology.

The server will pull the data from an external API, save it to MongoDB via Mongoose.  I then need to push the new data to the client

If anyone has any suggestions that would be great!

***Environment***

Node.js with Express v4.16.4
React-Native v0.58.0-rc.2
Mongoose v5.4.5

Firebase is already installed in the react-native app. I'm proficient with both Mongoose and Firebase so either one could be good for the push queue if applicable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**1. can use socket.io**
   Server send data to client using Web socket(socket.io).

**2. can use firebase push notification.**
   Server can create new notification to firebase, and client can received signal from firebase, and get data from server via REST api.

Comment: Thanks King!  Would I basically just write the data I want to send to the client to firebase real time database and then have my react-native client listen for changes to real time database?  One piece I still don't understand is how to make sure the correct user receives the correct data?

Comment: Sockets.io is a great solution for ‘broadcasting’ data changes to connected clients.